# Clojure: Wrong argument number for 'assert'?

Tags: clojure, assert

I'm learning Clojure and am messing around on the REPL. For `assert`, the documentation says

```
Usage: (assert x)
   (assert x message)

Evaluates expr and throws an exception if it does not evaluate to
logical true.
```

So I expected `(assert false "Error message")` to raise an error and output `"Error message"`. However, it gives

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args (4) passed to: core$assert (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Why does it say I have four arguments, and what would be the correct usage? The documentation to `assert` is not too verbose.

Comment: On Clojure 1.3.0 `(assert false "Error message")` entered in the REPL causes `AssertionError Assert failed: Error message`. I guess we'll need more details to help.

Comment: Thanks. I've got Version 1.2.1, and it gives exactly the output above. OK, maybe they've changed the behaviour.

Comment: Yes, Jan is correct. Behaviour changed between versions 1.2.1 and 1.3.0 - the optional message argument was added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried it out on 1.2.1 and I get the same behavior as you.

Then I tried `(doc assert)` on 1.2.1 in REPL as well:

```
clojure.core/assert
([x])
Macro
  Evaluates expr and throws an exception if it does not evaluate to
 logical true.
```

It seems that the message was added in 1.3 so you can only use the version with one parameter in 1.2.

If you are browsing online documentation be sure you are reading the correct version. Whenever in doubt type `(doc the-function-or-macro-name)` in REPL and see the documentation right there. I use `doc` much more often than online docs - it's always up to date with the version I'm using and it's already right there under my fingers anyway.

Comment: I see it was a stupid version issue. I've taken the snapshot from 1.4.0 and it works as Jan said. Thanks guys.